# Android zoomToSpan for MapsForge map

Tags: android, zooming

Is there exists zoomToSpan method for MapsForge map?
If not exists how can I implement it?
Is there anywhere some code sample or algorithm description?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend MapView with following method (MapsForge version 0.3.1):

```
public synchronized void fitToBoundingBox(final BoundingBox pBoundingBox, final int pMaximumZoom) {
    int width = this.getWidth();
    int height = this.getHeight();
    if (width <= 0 || height <= 0) {
        this.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                MapView.this.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                fitToBoundingBox(pBoundingBox, pMaximumZoom);
            }
        });
    } else {
        Projection projection1 = this.getProjection();
        GeoPoint pointSouthWest = new GeoPoint(pBoundingBox.minLatitude, pBoundingBox.minLongitude);
        GeoPoint pointNorthEast = new GeoPoint(pBoundingBox.maxLatitude, pBoundingBox.maxLongitude);
        Point pointSW = new Point();
        Point pointNE = new Point();
        byte maxLvl = (byte) Math.min(pMaximumZoom, this.getMapZoomControls().getZoomLevelMax());
        byte zoomLevel = 0;
        while (zoomLevel < maxLvl) {
            byte tmpZoomLevel = (byte) (zoomLevel + 1);
            projection1.toPoint(pointSouthWest, pointSW, tmpZoomLevel);
            projection1.toPoint(pointNorthEast, pointNE, tmpZoomLevel);
            if (pointNE.x - pointSW.x > width) {
                break;
            }
            if (pointSW.y - pointNE.y > height) {
                break;
            }
            zoomLevel = tmpZoomLevel;
        }
        this.getMapViewPosition().setMapPosition(new MapPosition(pBoundingBox.getCenterPoint(), zoomLevel));
    }
}
```

Most likely you have set of overlays that should be shown on the map. You have to find 'min' and 'max' values for Longitude and Latitude and then call method above:

```
mapView.fitToBoundingBox(new BoundingBox(minLat, minLng, maxLat, maxLng), 20);
```

Have found this solution [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mapsforge-dev/MChsbAK1vl4)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have achieved displaying the map in the emulator I have given the sample code for the zoom view features in the maps. Hope this helps

Keep the Main.xml file as follows:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
         android:layout_height="fill_parent">

         <com.google.android.maps.MapView 
             android:id="@+id/mapView"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:enabled="true"
             android:clickable="true"
             android:apiKey="0l4sCTTyRmXTNo7k8DREHvEaLar2UmHGwnhZVHQ"
             />

         <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/zoom" 
             android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
             android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
             android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
             /> 

     </RelativeLayout>
```

and the mapsActivity as follows:

```
     package net.learn2develop.GoogleMaps;

     import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
     import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
     import com.google.android.maps.MapView.LayoutParams;  

     import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.view.View;
     import android.widget.LinearLayout;

     public class MapsActivity extends MapActivity 
     {    
         MapView mapView; 

         /** Called when the activity is first created. */
         @Override
         public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
         {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             setContentView(R.layout.main);


             mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
             LinearLayout zoomLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.zoom);  
             View zoomView = mapView.getZoomControls(); 

             zoomLayout.addView(zoomView, 
                 new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                     LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                     LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 
             mapView.displayZoomControls(true);

         }

         @Override
         protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             return false;
         }
     }
```

Comment: Hello

Sorry, my question target was the Mapsforge (http://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/) off-line map. 
As I realized, in the org.mapsforge.android.maps.MapView not contain zoomToSpan method (I didn't find it)
The on-line map of google I already implemented the usage of map and it1s related things into my Android application. (you can it in the Android section of my webpage)

Thank you of your response.